# I turned my wife into a Vampire and now I can't find her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

*Platform: PS3*

I was completing quests for the Vampires at Castle Volkihar and took a quest to turn my wife, Ysolda, into a Vampire like myself. I did and she thanked me the next day. Now a couple of days have passed and I've come back to my house to find that she's gone. I remember the Vampire I did the quest for said that she was now "part of the family" but I searched the castle and she wasn't there either. I'd very much like to find her, but have no idea where she could have gone.

Comment: The issues we face. Turn your wife into a terror of the night, and she sods off.

Comment: Have you tried not using a mirror to look for her?

Comment: This should relly be tagged skyrim-dawnguard, since it's about the DLC

Answer (score 3):

She might have been killed by a npc because they attack Vampires when they see them

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC you could try to spawn her via console. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: The question is tagged with PS3.

Comment: Which is actually the incorrect use of that tag, since it's not a question about PS3 hardware, the OS, or a PS3 only feature.

Comment: I apologize. I failed to notice the tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple actually (if you are on PC)

1. Open up the console by typing '~'
2. Type prid 0001A69A
3. moveto player

Now, 2 cases are possible,

1. A dead body is teleported to you.

   - Simple, select the body, and type resurrect.
2. An alive and chirpy Ysolda greets you.

-Talk to her and ask to move the house.

(This may contain typos, as I am on an android device currently, so if you spot any, please contact me, and I'll respond ASAP)

Comment: The question is tagged with PS3

Comment: Yeah he's on PS3